# DataStax Cassandra Community Server 2.1.2 doesn't start

Tags: cassandra, datastax

My OS is Windows 8.1, 64.
I have recently downloaded and installed the DataStax Community Edition v2.1.2 from http://planetcassandra.org/cassandra , after finishing the installation the DataStax Cassandra Community Server 2.1.2 doesn't start and when I try to start it, it stops again ( whereas two others services DataStax OpsCenter Agent 2.1.2 and DataStax OpsCenter Community 2.1.2 are running), and when I try connecting to 127.0.0.1/9160 the below exception raises :

> [default@unknown] connect 127.0.0.1/9160;
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Conn
>   ection refused: connect at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
>          at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TFramedTransportFactory.openTransport(TFramedTransportFactory.java:41)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.connect(CliMain.java:66)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeConnect(CliClient.java:2394)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java:284)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.java:203)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:333)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>          at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>          at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>          at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
>          ... 7 more
>   Exception connecting to 127.0.0.1/9160. Reason: Connection refused: connect.

I have installed v2.0.11 without any problem,
how can I fix this problem in v2.1.2 (also I've defined Java_Home)

Regards

Comment: Can you post any errors on startup from system.log or output.log ?

Comment: I checked system.log, it was empty and I couldn't found output.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra.bat and change "jamm-0.2.6.jar" to "jamm-0.2.8.jar".  Sorry about that error..  This has been fixed for the 2.1.3 release.

Yesterday, I posted a nightly snapshot of pre-2.1.3 msi package for another user, so there are additional fixes on top of Cassandra 2.1.2 - here are the mis and checksum:

http://scp.datastax.com/~mshuler/datastax-community-64bit_2.1.2.msi
http://scp.datastax.com/~mshuler/datastax-community-64bit_2.1.2.msi.md5

**Update:** I'm re-rolling the msi and hope to have an updated installer published soon.

Comment: the cassandra.bat isn't in path \apache-cassandra\conf, it is in the \apache-cassandra\bin. and also it itself has "jamm-0.2.8.jar" not "jamm-0.2.6.jar"

Comment: I downloaded and installed the Cassandra 2.1.2 from the link you put and it works well

Comment: The links are dead!